# Probability at a point

Tags: probability-theory, soft-question, random-variables

If X is a continuous random variable then we say that probability at a point is neglected or id zero.but if it is discrete then the probablity of that point will be taken into consideration
I know i may sound stupid but still i wanted to ask  when we have pdf we can always calculate probability at a point by putting that point in the pdf? Please can somebody explain
For ex if we have $P(X\le a)=P(X\lt a)$ if $X$ is a continuous random variable.
But we can have $P(X\lt a)=P(X\le a)-P(X=a)$
Where am i wrong??

Comment: Nothing's wrong.  As you said, $P(X=a)=0$ if $X$ is continuous so both of your equalities say the same thing.

Comment: Ye but can't i calculate $P(X=a)$ by using the pdf

Comment: Sure you can.  Integrate from $a$ to $a$.  By properties of integrals, it equals $0$.

Comment: Why would i integrate this from $a$ to $a$ i cant i simply put the value of $a$ in the pdf for ex if $X$ follows $exp (2)$ and i wanted to find P(X=1) then this would be $2e^{-2}$

Comment: Because with continuous variables, the value of the pdf at a point is a probability density, not a probability.  The outputs of the probability mass function of a discrete variable and of the probability density function of a continuous variable are not the same sort of thing.

Comment: For instance, plug in all possible real numbers into the exponential pdf you describe -- the numbers would not sum to 1.

Comment: Okk thanx barry..i have just one more curiousity about this and i think that related to what you call 'probability density' suppose $X$ follows $U(0,0.5)$the pdf would be $f_X(x)=2$..but that doesn't make sense..what is it??

Comment: Then the pdf of X is 2 for $0 < x < 0.5$ and 0 elsewhere.  The probability of  $X$ landing in an interval $[a,b]$ in $[0,0.5]$ is $2(a-b)$ (the integral of the pdf from $a$ to $b$).

Comment: Thnxx Barry i understood what you said ..

Comment: It's not just @Barry who calls this a 'probability density' :-)